# How to lock the tab focus on a modal in typescript?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, angular, typescript

I have a bootstrap modal with two button elements. When the modal is opened, the buttons get the focus but when I tab twice, the focus leaves the modal and goes to some other element on the main screen.

So, my question is how to lock the tab focus on the modal, i.e., tabbing on the first button, the focus should go to the next button, and tabbing on the second button should get back the focus onto the first button.

I have seen the similar query in other questions where they were asking to use ids to the tags which I don't want to implement.

The following is the modal:

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Are you sure?</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                warning
            </div>
        <div class="modal-footer ok-cancel">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="delete()" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And also, I might have more modals in future where I could have more elements on the modal. In that case, how could I achieve this?

PS: I am implementing this in an Angular2 framework with typescript.

Comment: Listen to the tab key, see if it's coming from the last input in the modal, if it is, cancel the event and set focus on the first input. Do the same thing backwards checking for `e.shiftKey`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement the following method:

```
private tabKey(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        let parentModal = $(document).find('.modal');
        //List of html elements which can be focused by tabbing.
        let focusableElementsArrayString = 'a[href], input:not([disabled]), select:not([disabled]), textarea:not([disabled]), button:not([disabled]), iframe, object, embed, [tabindex="0"]';
        let focusableElementsInModal = parentModal.find(focusableElementsArrayString);
        let numberOfElements = focusableElementsInModal.length;
        let firstTabElement = focusableElementsInModal[0];
        let lastTabElement = focusableElementsInModal[numberOfElements - 1];
        // Check for Shift + Tab
        if (event.keyCode === 9 && event.shiftKey) {
            if (document.activeElement === firstTabElement) {
                event.preventDefault();
                lastTabElement.focus();
            } // Check for Tab
        } else if (event.keyCode === 9) {
            if (document.activeElement === lastTabElement) {
                event.preventDefault();
                firstTabElement.focus();
            }
        }
    }
```

I have even implemented the shift+tab for you in the code. Hope that helps.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad I was able to help! By the way, there are couple more focusable elements like area[href], [contenteditable]. you can add those if you want in the string. Cheers.

Comment: If you did not want to use jquery with this script. You could querySelector and querySelectorAll to get the parentModel and focusable elements.